# sed regexp pattern misunderstanding

Tags: sed

I try to parse log prase by sed:

```
echo 195.236.222.1 - - [24/Jul/2012:07:35:25 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 387 "http://www.google.fi/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=tarinat&source=web&cd=9&ved=0CGoQFjAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.suomi24.fi%2F&ei=XyQOUKi0CeWA4gTjz4D4Cg&usg=AFQjCNE6wg5zPXup3d3PRoqU-BtpiNCccw" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1" |
sed -r 's/.*(\&q=.*)\&.*/\1/'
```

I would like to get "&q=tarinat" but unfortunately have:

```
\&q=tarinat&source=web&cd=9&ved=0CGoQFjAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.suomi24.fi%2F&ei=XyQOUKi0CeWA4gTjz4D4Cg
```

Don't understand the reason why I get the whole string till the end. Any assistance or hints would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The regex `.*` is greedy.  You don't want it to be greedy, so you should probably write:

```
sed -r 's/.*(\&q=[^&]*)\&.*/\1/'
```

Comment: Note `/s` should be transposed and you're missing an ending `)`.

Comment: @Thor: now you know why I'm not a copy typist; I can't copy!

Answer (score 3):

The `.*` is quite greedy. You could replace this with a negative character match `[^&]*` which says match anything but a `&` character

```
echo 195.236.222.1 - - [24/Jul/2012:07:35:25 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 387 "http://www.google.fi/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=tarinat&source=web&cd=9&ved=0CGoQFjAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.suomi24.fi%2F&ei=XyQOUKi0CeWA4gTjz4D4Cg&usg=AFQjCNE6wg5zPXup3d3PRoqU-BtpiNCccw" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1" |
sed -r 's/.*(\&q=[^&]*)\&.*/\1/'
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way using `grep`:

```
grep -o "&q=[^&]*"
```

Result:

```
&q=tarinat
```